# A username and password are being requested by http://127.0.0.1:8080. The site says: "XDB"

Tags: firefox

Starting today I suddenly get this request evertime I start firefox or open a new tab in firefox.

```
A username and password are being requested by http://127.0.0.1:8080. The site says: "XDB"
```

I do not have a clue what its asking me, anybody has any idea what this is and how to get rid of it other then reinstalling firefox ?

Now Chrome also start asking me the same question.
Malwarebytes does not finds anything and Avast antivirus also does not finds anything.
Searching for this error in google only leads to oracle login problems, what does oracle has to do with firefox and chrome ?

Comment: If you downvote my question than be a man and tell me why

Answer (score 2):

127.0.0.1 is your local machine. Apparently you have a webserver running on port 8080 and Firefox is trying to load something from there. Did you install some new software or Firefox add-in?

Comment: I know its mmy local machine but I have not installed any new software nor add-in. Also, chrome has now also started asking me this question. Is there a way in firefox to see which add-on or plugin is active at that time ?